# Not rewriting URLs for existing content using Virtuoso rules based URL Rewriter

Tags: url-rewriting, semantic-web, virtuoso

I'm using [Virtuoso's rule base URL Rewriter](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/urlrewriting.html) and I want to tell it not to rewrite a URL if a file actually exists at the specified URL. Using Apache and mod_rewrite the relevant `RewriteCond`s would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But I can't find an alternative for this in [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a kind of hacky solution to this problem. Instead of a generic "don't match where a file exists" condition I ended up creating new rules ("Rule matching: First matching") above the actual rewrite rule I wanted. These rules specifically excluded directories like "images" etc...